# HTML Input file upload saved as very long url without PHP, AJAX, or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I have a website where you can upload files and it will be saved in a database, but is there a way where the url doesn't have to be 1 million characters long? Here's the code for uploading

```
function readImg(input, eltID) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                document.getElementById(eltID).style.backgroundImage = 'url('+e.target.result+')';
            };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
}
```

Which generates this:

[image]

Any solution?

I'm also not using any form. Using input type=file

Comment: This library encodes image, thats the reason, its too long

Comment: but how to not encode it? I'm using the built in filereader.

Comment: Try changing the upload form from `GET` to `POST`...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto. The thing is `readAsDataURL` this converts image to base64 encoded

Comment: I'm not using any form

Comment: @KinoBacaltos. You can try this with html and PHP

Comment: Is there any alternative to the readAsDataUrl which doesn't do this long text but still works?

Comment: I don't want PHP though. I want pure-javascript stuff

Comment: @KinoBacaltos How do you do upload image file, without a `<FORM>` tag?

Comment: BTW, many web servers limit the length of URL. Do not expect it working with URL longer than 8192 bytes...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Doesn't facebook, twitter, and other websites upload profile pictures and those stuff without forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the image data *somewhere*.

At the moment you appear to be choosing to store it in a `data:` scheme URL.

You can't reduce the size of that without making the total amount of image data smaller (e.g. by degrading the quality).

If you want a short URL, then make the URL be a reference to the image (e.g. store the file on a file system and put a static HTTP server in front of it, then the URL will be based on the filename you save the image as).

Comment: So i have to convert the data URLs to files? Idk how jquery makes files. I only want pure javascript code.

Comment: They start off as files. You're doing something to convert them to URLs.

Comment: Quentin Well, yes, they start off as files but what happens if i don't convert them to urls? I don't know much about FileReader since I am actually giving it to a socket.io server nd storing it into a database.

Comment: @KinoBacaltos — If you don't convert them to URLs then you have some binary image data, which isn't text, so it can't be stored in the JSON.

Comment: Should I convert DataURIs to files and then get them by path?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the "upload" part?
Anyhow on the client side you can use createObjectURL

```
function readImg(input, eltID) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0])
    document.getElementById(eltID).style.backgroundImage = 'url('+url+')'
  }
}
```